# How to harmonize ^4 ^2 after a ii7 chord?

Tags: voice-leading

I am busy trying to complete an exercise in which I have to harmonize a soprano melody using supertonic and subdominant harmony where the red stars are marked. I am allowed to use inversions. I got stuck in bar 5 where the blue arrow is pointing. Could anybody give me a hand and tell me what chords could go in this space? I only have the main diatonic chords to work with and have to follow the ii7 with some kind of dominant family chords. The problem I have is that the D in the soprano wouldnt resolve if I used a V chord... This is what confuses me. So the only other chord that goes there is a vii°6.. maybe that could go to a V7 chord?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Stick on the E chord for 2 beats.   The D DOES resolve to C♯, the B just delays it.  That's OK.   A very common cadential cliche in hymn-style writing!

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Wont the 7th be transfered to another voice if I keep the E7 on both beats? If the answer is yes then wont it need to resolve too?

Comment: See expanded answer above.

Comment: Thank you Lawrence. I had thought of that but the reason that I didn't use that is because I thought that going from a V7 to a V on the second beat before moving back to I was somehow not allowed. But if this solution is acceptable then fantastic!

Comment: You're not really going from V7 to V.   Just decorating the V7 a bit.  Look at the first two beats of that bar as all V7.